# Custom object and use it

Tags: java, android, class, object

[image]I have a custom class for a object like below :

```
public class StudentState implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3001666080405760977L;

    public CourseState CourseState;

    public class CourseState implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -631172412478493444L;

        public List<Lessonstates> lessonstates;

    }

    public class Lessonstates implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5209770078710286360L;
        public int state;

    }
}
```

Now I want to initialise Lessonstates in my code to use it. I've done this but it has an error :

```
CourseState state = test.new CourseState();
Lessonstates newLesson = state.new Lessonstates();
```

I've tried this as well:

```
 Lessonstates newLesson = new CourseState().new Lessonstates();
```

The error is StudentState.CourseState.Lessonstates cannot be resolved to a type
Does anyone can help me how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to instantiate `Lessonstates` from a `StudentState`, same as `CourseState` :

```
StudentState test = new StudentState();
CourseState state = test.new CourseState();
Lessonstates newLesson = test.new Lessonstates();
```

Since both `CourseState` and `Lessonstates` are inner classes to `StudentState`.

Otherwise, you could take our inner classes out of `StudentState`, or make them static to be able to instantiate them without a `StudentState` instance.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite simple:

```
CourseState state = new CourseState();
state.lessonstates = new ArrayList<Lessonstates>();
```

objects need to be allocated before they can be accessed. Once allocated you can access his member with the `.` (dot) notation

Comment: So how can I use NewLesson then ? for example how can i set NewLesson.state = 1 ; ? @blackbelt

Comment: Lessonstates lessonState = new Lessonstates(); lessonState.state = 1;

Comment: @blackbely but it says: No enclosing instance of type StudentState is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type StudentState

Comment: post the exact code. It is impossible to understand what s going on. Still the rule is always the same, and it is basic java. It is not android related

Comment: why an image? Cant you simple copy/paste? What is test.new CourseState(); ?

Comment: ok sorry, I removed test and wrote CourseState state = new CourseState(); and again I have No enclosing instance of type StudentState is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type StudentState (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of StudentState).